# SSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

**

> I got error during add dependency via composer.

**

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. Open   SSL Error
>   messages:   error:1416F086:SSL
>   routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>   Failed to enable crypto   failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: Add more info. Too short to understand. Like what is causing this problem, your dev environment etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had that same error on a virtual machine with its date/time not synced. So check that the date/time of the machine running composer is correctly synced. In my case, using Vagrant, I just had to halt and restart the machine.